# How do I hide an element higher up the tree by hovering on an element lower down the tree

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide the element with class = "product-details-card" by hovering over the element with class = "v-content__wrap".

See this website

```
http://webtest.brooksbingham.com/module/bespokestudio/viewer#/
```

This is a part of my code:

```
<div class="product-details-card">
  card
</div>

<main class="v-content">
  <div class="v-content__wrap">
    <div class="viewport-wrapper">
       1234
      <canvas>

    </div>
 </div>
</main>
```

This is a codepen:

```
https://codepen.io/boidurja-talukdar/pen/dybjQrq
```

I tried using javascript. But it was not working.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("v-content__wrap")[0].onmouseover = f1();

document.getElementsByClassName("v-content__wrap")[0].onmouseout = f2();

function f1() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("product-details-card")[0].style.display = "none";
}

function f2() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("product-details-card")[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

Note: I can't change the html code since it is in Prestashop.

Comment: by using javascript.  also in future please put the code in the question itself - links to codepen must be acoompanied by the code in the question itself, that's why you were asked to put code in the question - getting around this by marking the links as code is annoying in 2 ways -1 you blatantly ignored the warning, 2 we can no longer click on the links

Comment: You can't with plain CSS, since there is not a parent selector. You can achieve it only using JavaScript

Comment: @CristianTraìna How to do it in javascript?

Comment: @BoidurjaTalukdar try something, then if you have JS problems we can help.

Answer (score 0):

When setting these functions:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("v-content__wrap")[0].onmouseover = f1();

document.getElementsByClassName("v-content__wrap")[0].onmouseout = f2();
```

Do NOT invoke them (add the parenthesis). You are setting the `mouseover` and `mouseout` to the return values of these functions, not the functions themselves. Since the return value is `null` nothing will happen. Do this instead:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("v-content__wrap")[0].onmouseover = f1;

document.getElementsByClassName("v-content__wrap")[0].onmouseout = f2;
```

I'd also recommend setting an explicit height/width to the `v-content__wrap` element because when you set the `display` to none, there is a chance that your mouse will no longer be hovering over that element (try mouseenter from the bottom) and will lead to flickering. Alternatively, you could set the `opacity` to 0